# approximating zeroes of solution of a given second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y$ be a solution of $(1+x^2)y''+(1+4x^2)y=0$ where $x>0$ and
>   $y(0)=0$. Then $y$ has
>
> - $(a)$ infinitely many solutions in $[0,1]$.
> - $(b)$ infinitely many zeroes in $[1,\infty)$.
> - $(c)$ at least $n$ zeroes in $[0,n\pi]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
> - $(d)$ at most $3n$ zeroes in $[0,n\pi]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I compared the equation with $$y''+y=0$$ with $y(0)=0$ to get $y(x)=\sin x$. Now between two consecutive zeroes of $\sin x$, there exists a zero of the given equation. Now for the options,

- $(b)$ is true as $\sin x$ has infinitely many zeroes in $[1,\infty)$, so has the solution of the given ODE.
- $(c)$ is also true as $[0,n\pi]=[0,\pi]\cup[\pi,2\pi]\cup\dots\cup[(n-1)\pi,n\pi]$, and each contains two consecutive zeroes of $\sin x$, therefore one solution of the given ODE.
- But $(d)$ says there are $\color{red}{at \ most}$ $3n$ zeroes in $[0,n\pi]$, which I'm unable to justify. By comparison theorem I can justify the minimum number of zeroes, which is $n$, but what about the maximum?
- Again how to confirm whether $[0,1]$ contains either finitely many or infinitely many solutions of the given ODE?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In (a), does it really mean "solutions" as in "solutions of the ODE" or does it mean the zeros or roots of any fixed solution of the ODE? What is weakly associated is that the power series expansion around $x=0$ of the general solution has radius of convergence $1$ due to the poles at $x=\pm i$.

Answer (score 3):

You determined and used that $$1\le1+\frac{3x^3}{1+x^2}.$$ Similarly, you can divide the polynomials with the quadratic term as focus to find $$\frac{1+4x^2}{1+x^2}=4-\frac{3}{1+x^2}\le 4,$$ so that you can also apply the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem to the given equation and
$$
y''+4y=0.
$$
From there you get that there are at most $2n+1$ solutions in $[0,n\pi]$.

---

(*2024/04/12*) The separation statement of the comparison theorem is true for all solutions $\sin(2(x-c))$ of the harmonic equation. So if $t_k$ is one of the roots of $y$, set $c=t_k-\epsilon$. Then the next root $t_k+\frac\pi2-\epsilon$ of the sine comes before $t_{k+1}$. Thus the roots of $y$ are at least $\frac\pi2$ apart. This gives $2n$ roots in general, and $2n+1$ roots in the special case of the harmonic equation with $y(x)=\sin(2x)$ as solution.

As the actual upper bound is $\omega^2=4-\frac{3}{1+(n\pi)^2}<4$, the root separation $\frac{\pi}{\omega}$ is actually larger than $\frac{\pi}2$, completely precluding the case with $2n+1$ roots.

Comment: At most $2n(+1?)$ solutions, then? But the answer says $(d)$ is a correct one, so there should be at most $3n$ solutions.

Comment: Yes, for $n\ge 1$ you have $2n+1\le 3n$. Between any two roots of $y$ you have at least one root of $\cos(2x)$, and as that has $2n$ roots in $[0,n\pi]$, $y$ can have at most $2n+1$ roots.

Comment: @LutzLehmann solution $sin(2x)$ has $2n+1$ zeros in $[0,n\pi]$ so original ODE solution has at most $2n+2$ zeros which is not less than $3n$. Am I right ?

Comment: @neelkanth : How do you justify $2n+2$? $\sin(2x)$ already is the most extreme arrangement of roots for a solution of $y''+qy=0$ with $0<q\le 4$. One could even say that the roots at the boundary only count as $1/2$ each, any slight shift to $\sin(2x+c)$ will have one of them move outside the interval.

Comment: @LutzLehmann between any two zero of a (non zero)solution of given ODE there is at least one zero of solution of ODE $y’’+4y=0$ say $sin(2x)$.

Comment: If I choose $n=1$ then $sin(2x)$ has $3$ zeros in $[0,\pi]$ so then given  ODE solutions has at most $4$ zeros .

Comment: So you are referring to an example with $$t_1=0< t_2 \le \frac\pi2\le t_3<\pi=t_4.$$ But $\sin(2t-2c)$ is also a solution of the harmonic equation, select $0<c<t_2$. Also, one can select $c$ so that that none of the roots of the sine coincides with with one of the finitely many roots of $y$ in the interval. For the root sequence one has now, in the minimal case (the roots of $y$ can jump over multiple roots of the sine), $$0=t_1<c<t_2<\frac\pi2+c<t_3<\pi+c<t_4,$$ so that $t_4$ has to lie outside the interval, which contradicts the assumption.